# C# application with database works fine but after deploy doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I created a c# application with database and everything works perfect in Visual Studio , I can read , insert and delete from database   ,but after i deploy my application i can read ,but can't insert and delete. When i try to insert or delete my application show catch error. In Visual Studio everything works perfect ,but when i deploy and install application i have this problem. I deployed my application with Setup Project and in my application folder i added all files from debug folder.

And here is my connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Baza-de-date.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

I'm using VS 2013 and Microsoft SQL Server

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English.

Comment: Does the deployed application use the same database?
Also check if it runs with the same user and / permissions.

What exact error message do you get? what is the line of code where it happens.

Comment: Do you have LocalDb installed where you're deploying it?

Comment: Yes , use the same database. I receive catch exception error.

Comment: Here is my app : https://www.dropbox.com/s/36j6uu0ng9a9vfx/app.rar

Comment: Was the database deployed with the application, or created on first run? If the database was deployed, then make sure the user on the deployment machine has access to the database that was deployed.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight , database is deployed with the application

Comment: Then my recommendation stands: ensure the user account under which the website is running on the deployment machine has access rights to the deployed database.

Comment: In what folder does the DB reside after deployment? Has the user write permissions in that folder? And of course, why don't you show us the exact error message? What does it say, exactly?

Comment: @fourpastmidnight, how can i verify user access to database?

Comment: In Server Manager in Visual Studio, connect to the database (if it's not already connected), expand it, and go to Security\Users. Add the user that needs access to the database if the user isn't already present. The user probably needs read/write access.

Comment: After deployment database is in the same folder with the application. Is not an error , my application jump to exception written by me .

Comment: Looking at your previous question I noticed that your catch doens't show anything about the exception. You should change that code and print also the value of the Exception.Message field. With that info is more easier to diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must check following Item:

- The name of operational database was equal to name of develop database.
- User name and password that used in develop equal to User Name and password that used in operational database.
- Your User name have enough permission.
- Assigned folder exists and .mdf file not in read only mode.
- you have enough permission for this folder.